# AWS connect case is not updating from Postman. user is not authorized to perform: cases:* on resource: * with an explicit deny" }

Tags: amazon-connect

I'm  trying to update a case on Amazon Connect but facing explicit deny issue. I'm able to get case but when I try to update it, explicit deny error occurred. Below is a screenshot of that. Can anyone tell what I'm missing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNuN1.png)

I' have also tried to update permissions and gave cases permissions but no luck